# treading on somebody's toes - dealing with mischievous tormentor

Tags: discussion, down-votes, moderation, ethics

I think I might anger someone recently, because in just a few seconds someone downvoted all my answers that I've ever posted on SO. Can I defend myself somehow from such behaviour?

[image: Here's a picture of what it looks like.]

I know it's childish to pursue reputation points, but I don't like to think that someone can actually downvote your posts just because he got mad on one of your recent comments or answers. Personal rumbling are the last thing I'd like to see on a knowledge-base website.

Comment: It's indeed a duplicate and related topic is helpfull. Sorry and thank you for your help :),

Comment: This has been dealt with.